# Accepted publickey for userx from y.y.y.y (ssh authentication)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, unix, centos

Server A and B is setup for autoSSH

I am on ServerA (y.y.y.y) and is accessing ServerB.

I understand that A's public key is store in B and is use by B to encrypt the challenge to A when A connect. A then use its private key to decrypt the challenge.

When Server A ssh to B. I saw this in the /var/adm/message in B

> Jul 10 10:04:25 serverB sshd[7703]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted
>   publickey for oracle from y.y.y.y port 50910 ssh2

q1) Why is A is sending its public key to B ? I thought B should be the 1 sending the public key challenge ?

Comment: It's just saying that the publickey for oracle on A is accepted as authentication.

Answer (score 2):

a1) The public key authentication can work in two phases (as described in [RFC4252]). The first one is "MAY type" and the message contains the public key to verify on server that the user is able to be allowed to access this account with this key. This is made to avoid unnecessary processing and user interaction, especially when you send your public keys on every server where you don't have set up passwordless authentication.

Your description is the step 2, which continues if the first one succeeds (most of the client implementations). The first one is not sufficient, since it doesn't prove the possession of private key (that is proved by the signature of challenge).

[RFC4252] https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4252.txt